# creating view controller storyboard vs programmatically - performance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There are many questions comparing building UI in storyboard vs programmatically but my question is does anyone have any **data** showing which approach has better performance in the app?

like if you had two UIViewController which have exactly the same ui but one was made in storyboard and another from code. If you present them each from another UIViewController ... which loads faster?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @rmaddy noob here. how can i measure that?

Comment: You can use the time profiler Instrument, but my guess is that the difference in performance will be virtually nil

Comment: Storyboards are slower.. They are XML that gets compiled into a byte-code like language and then when instantiated, it does `initWithDecoder` constructor on the controller and all its views.. You can actually serialize and deserialize UIViews because it conforms to `NSCoding`. You can see that someone has actually tested it here: https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/load-from-nib-or-construct-views-in.html as well.. However, it's absolutely insanely negligible!! Choose whichever you feel is right. Not because of performance because in this case, it doesn't matter..

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of "premature optimization". You'd need sensitive measurements to even detect the difference in performance between code-based creation of view controllers and storyboard-based creation. The difference is going to be at least a couple of orders of magnitude smaller than what a human can perceive. If one takes .0002 seconds, and the other takes .001 seconds, who cares?

Thus you should use the approach that is clearest and easiest to develop and to maintain. (That would be Storyboards, by a wide margin.)

Comment: `Clearest and easiest to develop and to maintain. (That would be Storyboards, by a wide margin)` no way! Storyboards are NOT the easiest to maintain. When you need to change a single constraint sometimes you end up breaking a ton of others. When you work on a massive team you end up with conflicts and some are insane to solve. Code is the most maintainable by a long shot. As for easiest, that's subjective. With iOS 9's `NSLayoutAnchor` code is much easier.

Comment: If multiple members of a team are working on the same storyboard that's a sign that it needs to be broken up.